# Изучение Spring (план / схема)

Tags: java, spring

Задался вопросом изучения Spring, много информации, много видео, много книг, но нет ни одного плана / схемы, иллюстрации последовательности действий.

Должен быть четкий алгоритм, изучить основы Spring, что такое фреймворк вообще, из чего он состоит, что из себя представляет, схему действия его подключения и его работы в процессе выполнения программы, далее допустим Spring core (Bean, Context) итп.

Знакомые советуют почитать *Spring in Action*, чем сейчас и занимаюсь, однако там все с использованием xml конфигураций, может в сл. главах будут аннотации и конфиги.

Вот и вопрос, если есть опытные Spring программисты, распишите грамотно последовательность/план/схему что за чем изучать?

Заранее спасибо.

PS: Если уже были такие темы, киньте ссылки.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ К:
Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

- Вы можете написать вывод в консоль, если не изучили как это сделать? нет.
- Вы можете написать цикл на языке, если не знаете синтаксис? нет.
- Вы можете написать блок-схему без знания описания действий? нет.
  Тогда какие прения могут порождать простейший алгоритм действий? Если вы не знаете как описать бины, вы не напишите ничего, если вы не знаете как привязать контекст, то далее и танцы с бубном не помогут.
  Вопрос до простоты конкретный, с возможными несколькими параллелями, примерный план для новичков, не понимаю в чем он может вызвать бесконечные споры? Приведите минимум 10 вариантов больших дискуссий и споров, можно со ссылками, после чего закрывайте его вовсе или ваше мнение ошибочно.

Заранее спасибо.
PS: Не ошибается лишь тот, кто ничего ни делает.

Comment: Spring Core,Spring MVC, Spring AOP, Spring Data, Spring Boot. А дальше по-желанию (или по мере необходимости): Spring Cloud Netflix Stack/Security/Batch/Actuator/Devtools/Reactive Stack/Integration.

Comment: Так и у тебя не вопрос _как написать вывод в консоль?_, или _как написать цикл?_

Comment: Верно, у меня более широкий вопрос, ))) просто он может разделять параллельные ветки обучения, но без определенных навыков, дальше ничего не изучишь, я уже подумал над вопросом более детально, обрисую все части попозже с конкретными вопросами. )))

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Самый быстрый способ изучать - это читать [Spring framework - документация на русском языке Основы Spring](https://spring-source.ru/), или [Spring Framework | Spring по-русски!](http://spring-projects.ru/projects/spring-framework/), или [Spring Documentation](https://spring.io/docs), и писать программы. [Вот](https://www.springbyexample.org/) еще один полезный ресурс.

Как писать программы? Это дается не сразу, но для этого можно читать тюториалы или записаться на курсы.

Если вам посчастливилось иметь книги то можно осваивать литературу, только правильно выбирать уровень, на который эта книга расчитана.

Answer (score 2):

Вам правильно советуют знакомые. Изучите по "Spring in Action" принципы работы фреймворка. Остальное "гуглится" на раз-два. Лично я никакого плана не составлял по изучению Spring. Прочитал "Spring in Action" и вперед, решать задачи рабочие при помощи фреймворка.