# Пузырьковая сортировка по книге Р. Лафоре

Tags: java, алгоритм, пузырьковая-сортировка

Есть реализация пузырьковой сортировки по книге Лафоре "Структуры данных и алгоритмы JAVA":

```
class ArrayBub {
private long[] a;
private int nElems;
public ArrayBub(int max) {
    a = new long[max];
    nElems = 0;
}
public void insert(long value) {
    a[nElems] = value;
    nElems++;
}
public void display() {
    for(int j=0; j<nElems; j++)
        System.out.print(a[j] + " ");
    System.out.println("");
}
public void bubbleSort() {
    int out, in;

    for(out=nElems-1; out>1; out--)
        for(in=0; in<out; in++)
            if( a[in] > a[in+1] )
                swap(in, in+1);
}
private void swap(int one, int two) {
    long temp = a[one];
    a[one] = a[two];
    a[two] = temp;
}}

class BubbleSortApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maxSize = 100;
    ArrayBub arr;
    arr = new ArrayBub(maxSize);

    arr.insert(77);
    arr.insert(99);
    arr.insert(44);
    arr.insert(55);
    arr.insert(22);
    arr.insert(88);
    arr.insert(11);
    arr.insert(00);
    arr.insert(66);
    arr.insert(33);

    arr.display();
    arr.bubbleSort();
    arr.display();
}}
```

но она не сортирует массив со значениями - [3, 2, 1] - ответ:  [2, 3, 1].

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем подвох?

Comment: Вы можете взять бумажку, ручку и провести ручную трассировку кода. Пошагово проследите, что происходит с вашими данными и где возникает ошибка.

Comment: Особо обратите внимание на граничные условия в циклах.

Comment: Почини функцию `bubbleSort()`, вместо `out > 1` нужно `out > 0`. А вообще, на будующее, есть такая замечательная вещь - дебаггер.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: @GlebKuznetsov и даже есть описание как пользоваться ↑↑ :)

Comment: спасибо за ответы, получается ошибка в книге

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для понимания алгоритма можно почитать, что такое [Пузырьковая сортировка](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC&stable=1). Правда там обход массива производится в прямом порядке для каждого элемента, но это не столь важно.

При работе с массивами надо смотреть на значения переменной индекса, правильность границ, инвариантов функции (assert), и т.д., потому что при неверных значениях переменных возникает неверное вычисление.

Как у вас, например сортируется часть массива, а оставшаяся часть не сортируется, т.е. массив остаётся неотсортированным, потому что он отсортирован не полностью.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, получается ошибка в книге

Comment: @Алиса Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/877886/204920) я написал, как нужно выбирать книги. Может понадобится в дальнейшем)

Comment: Спасибо большое!