# Источники информации по спрингу (книги, сайты... )

Tags: java, spring

Подскажите, какие книги или литературу стоит почитать по спрингу?

Я новичок и официальная документация на английском языке очень тяжело воспринимается. Может быть есть русскоязычные источники? Что посоветуете?

P. S. Пожалуйста не минусите, это правда важный вопрос.

Comment: @КириллМалышев ну вроде в этом вопросе автор указал "источники информации", по крайней мере в заголовке. На мой взгляд это несколько шире, чем просто "почитать", можно ещё и "посмотреть". В любом случае, я в своём ответе указал ещё и ссылку на видеоуроки на ютубе.

Comment: @КириллМалышев сделал соответствующую правку

Comment: Можете почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/877886/204920).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 2 русскоязычные книги (полноценные справочники):

- Spring 5 для профессионалов (Козмина Юлиана, Харроп Роб)
- Spring в действии (Крейг Уоллс)

Во второй из них информация устаревшая, так как перевод на русский только у третьего издания (2013 год), а в оригинале (на английском) есть уже шестое (2021).
Это важно, так как даже примеры конфигурации через xml файлы и аннотации сильно отличаются, и если вы новичок, то лучше учиться сразу по современным стандартам.

Поэтому, во-первых, я бы не рекомендовал вам изучать спринг по книгам (ну или хотя бы не только по ним), потому что информация быстро устаревает, особенно в русском переводе.

И во-вторых, изучать на английском языке из актуальных источников. Приведу несколько таких:

[официальная документация](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/)

https://www.baeldung.com/

[ресурс от Jetbrains по Spring Boot](https://hyperskill.org/knowledge-map/458)

Ещё есть видеоуроки, вы про них не спрашивали, но если понадобятся, то есть хороший курс коротких лекций на youtube:

[видеоуроки по Spring](https://youtu.be/3wBteulZaAs)

Они на русском, но я всё же очень советую изучить официальную документацию на английском языке.